# Hyperbolic Geometry (Proof of Rectangles)

Tags: proof-verification, hyperbolic-geometry

Recall that in hyperbolic geometry the interior angle sum for any triangle is less than 180◦. Using this fact prove that it is impossible to have a rectangle in hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: Well, can there be a polygon with four right angles? A right angle is still 90 degrees.

Comment: It might be possible to have a pentagon with 5 right angles though.

Comment: Can It be done knowing that a rectangle can be broken into 2 triangles and a triangle is less than 180 so a rectangle will be less than 360 making the rectangle not have 4 right angles

Comment: Precisely.  Precisely.